# Apache Samza: Getting Started with Samza REST and hello-samza

Tags: gradle, apache-samza

I am following the hello-samza tutorial on the [Apache Samza website](https://samza.apache.org/startup/hello-samza/latest/) and want to add a REST service as described here: http://samza.apache.org/learn/tutorials/latest/samza-rest-getting-started.html

I can see the samza jobs in YARN UI, but the following build command yields an error:

```
./gradlew samza-rest:clean releaseRestServiceTar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Task 'samza-rest' not found in root project 'hello-samza'.
```

Is it necessary to change the gradle build file from the [hello-samza repo](https://github.com/apache/samza-hello-samza)?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, the Samza version is 0.13.0.
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I think there is a typo in document. I believe the command should be `./gradlew :samza-rest:clean releaseRestServiceTar`
You are missing a ":" in front of samza-rest

Answer (score 0):

The `releaseRestServiceTar` task is defined in the `samza` project, not the `hello-samza` project.

You can clone the `samza` project by following [these instructions](http://samza.apache.org/contribute/code.html)